# How can I solve this error I get when I commit changes on an SVN repository from the Ubuntu terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal, svn

When I commit changes on a SVN repository, I always run into the following problem in the terminal in Ubuntu:

```
Error reading /home/ssylee/.nano_history: Permission denied
```

Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: As you can see, there are many ideas on how to solve it, but it kind of depends on why exactly you're experiencing the problem in the first place.

Comment: To reproduce: `sudo rm -f ~/.nano_history` (remove the file), `sudo nano somefile` (edit some file as root), `^K sometext` (search for some text), `^X` (exit), `nano somefile` (edit some file as you). You'll see **Error reading /home/ssylee/.nano_history: Permission denied**. nano creates .nano_history to store your search history. The file belongs to root if it is created during a `sudo nano` session.

Answer (score 28):

This is usually caused by running `sudo nano [file]`. This runs the nano process as root, but leaves `$HOME` set to the regular user's home directory, so if nano creates any files (including the .nano_history file), it will be owned by root and placed in your home directory.

You can verify this by running:

```
ls -l /home/ssylee/.nano_history
```

If `ls` reports that the file is owned by `root`, then you can be reasonably sure this was the cause.
If it is, then the situation can be repaired by running:

```
sudo chown $USER: ~/.nano_history
```

or to spell out that command:

```
sudo chown ssylee: /home/ssylee/.nano_history
```

A better habit to get into is to use `sudoedit` or `sudo -e` instead of `sudo nano`. This runs the `$EDITOR` program on a copy of the file being edited, and then atomically replaces the original file when the editor exits (which is very useful when editing system files).

By default, this may launch `vi`, but you can fix this temporarily by invoking it like so:

```
EDITOR=nano sudoedit [filename]
```

You can permanently configure `$EDITOR` in your `.bashrc`, or by placing

```
EDITOR=nano
```

in `/etc/environment`.

Comment: `chown $USER:` is a shorter way to apply the primary group.

Comment: @Tobu, thanks! i didn't know about that trick. I've updated the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest is to remove the file in question. The next easiest is to make it readable with `chmod`/`chown`. The next easiest is to use a different editor.

Answer (score 1):

I always use this:
`sudo chown -R username:username /home/username`

It solves the problem when the permissions are messed up.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather do a

```
ls -la /home/ssylee/.nano_history
```

first, to see the current permissions.
This might help you find out why they went wrong in the first place. If ssylee is the owner of this file, maybe you have a broken default umask?

Answer (score 1):

Just change the permissions of `.nano_history` file as follows:

```
sudo chown youruser:yourgroup /home/<username>/.nano_history
```

DONE! The message is gone! =)
Really is that simple.

Answer (score 0):

The fix requires editing the nano configuration file /etc/nanorc and deleting /home//.nano_history.

First comment out the set historylog parameter of nanorc with this command: sudo nano /etc/nanorc

```
#set historylog
```

This will disable  the ~/.nano_history file used for saving and reading search /replace strings.

This still leaves the .nano_history file in your user directory. Delete this file as follows:

```
sudo rm .nano_history
```

That’s it!

[Sources](http://pricklytech.wordpress.com/2010/12/12/ubuntu-nano-error-reading-home-nano_history-permission-denied/)

Comment: This will outright disable history in nano, probably not something users would want to do..